# My login jquery is not calling the php file correctly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

Hey im trying to write code for a login system, this is my first time and i used a tutorial online. The initial Javascript works fine and the errors show up when the inputs are left empty. However when i enter text in the inputs and click sign in, nothing happens. It seems to me like it is not calling the PHP file but i can't see any reason why it wouldnt as it is referenced correctly? Any help would greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
    include ("Includes/dbConnect.php");
    $u=$_POST['u'];
    $p=$_POST['p'];

    //Strip slashes
    $u = stripslashes($u);
    $p = stripslashes($p);

    //Strip tags 
    $u = strip_tags($u);
    $p = strip_tags($p);


    $check = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE login_user ='$u' AND login_pass='$p'")      or die(mysqli_error());
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($check !=="0"){
    $results = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE login_user = '$u'") or die(mysqli_error());
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            $login_user=$row['login_user'];
            session_register('login_user');
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $Login_user;
            echo "1";
    }
    }
?>
```

and here's the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sign_b_btn").live("click", function () {
            var u = $("#u").val();
            var p = $("#p").val();

            if (u == "") {
                $("#u").css("border-color", "red");
                $("#un").css("color", "red");
                $(".error").show().html("Please enter your username!");
                $("#p").css("border-color", "#606060");
                $("#up").css("color", "#333333");
            } else if (p == "") {
                $("#u").css("border-color", "#606060");
                $("#un").css("color", "#606060");
                $(".error").show().html("Please enter your Password!");
                $("#p").css("border-color", "red");
                $("#up").css("color", "red");
            } else {

                dataString = 'u=' + u + '&p=' + p;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Ajax/login_php.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        if (html == "") {
                            $(".error").show().html("The username or password you entered is incorrect!");
                            $("#p,#u").css("border-color", "red");
                            $("#up,#un").css("color", "red");
                        } else if (html == "1") {
                            $(".error").fadeOut(1000);
                            $("#u").css("border-color", "#606060");
                            $("#un").css("color", "#333333");
                            $("#p").css("border-color", "#606060");
                            $("#up").css("color", "#333333");
                            $(".center").animate({
                                opacity: 0.25,
                                left: '+=900',
                                height: 'toggle'
                            }, 5000, function () {
                                $(".done").slideDown(200).html("Welcome " + u);
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    var u = $("#u").val("");
                                    var p = $("#p").val("");
                                    window.location = "index.php";
                                }, 5000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console to see if there is are any errors? Or checked the network activity in your browser tools to see if the HTTP request is being made, and what it is returning?  You don't have an error callback, so if there is an error, nothing would happen.

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems from here, but it would be useful to know what's happening on the site. Do you get a 404 or 500 response from the server when the Ajax call takes place? Any JS errors? (You should be able to see these via Chrome's Network and Console tabs.) If it works, what does the server return? **Edit**: Sorry, Jason - writing too slowly...

Comment: Go to http://www.php-login-script.com and download the script(free of charge). It also use js to validate. You can **check** it.

Comment: hey thanks guys, checked the Network and Console in chrome, there is no javascript errors and the status of the php is OK in the network. how would i add error callback to the code??

Comment: hey i managed to fix was a problem with the sql, but now its giving this error <b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not consider global variables as a source of data, unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />

Comment: @user1269229 Google tells me that [this is because](http://preetul.wordpress.com/2007/05/07/your-script-possibly-relies-on-a-session-side-effect-which-existed-until-php-423-please-be-advised-that-the-session-extension-does-not-consider-global-variables-as-a-source-of-data-unles/) you used a global variable with the same name as a session variable. One of the comments says it may specifically be because of `session_register`, which is now deprecated (and actually duplicated by the `$_SESSION` line in your code, or at least it would be if you'd corrected the capital L in the variable name).

Comment: @user1269229 Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injections, which you should probably fix. :)

Comment: thanks for the help guys, its working now. how do i protect against SQL injections??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your session problem:

edit your php code so that your script starts off with a call to session_start();

eg:

```
<?php session_start();
 //rest of your php code
```

replace the lines :

```
session_register('login_user');
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $Login_user;
```

with:

```
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $Login_user;
```

You were getting the error that you mentioned because the function session_register(); has been deprecated in PHP version 5.3.0 and REMOVED from PHP version 5.4.0. $_SESSION is a global array that is available for you after session_start(); call.

Happy programming :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help guys, really helped me figure it out. Finished code if anyones interested:

```
<?php

include ("../Includes/dbConnect.php");
$u=$_POST['u'];
$p=$_POST['p'];

//Strip slashes
$u = stripslashes($u);
$p = stripslashes($p);

//Strip tags 
$u = strip_tags($u);
$p = strip_tags($p);



$query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE login_user ='$u' AND login_pass='$p'";
$check = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die("Couldn't execute query!");
$check = mysqli_num_rows($check);
if($check !=="0"){
$results = mysqli_query($cxn,"SELECT * FROM Login WHERE login_user = '$u' AND login_pass='$p'") or die("Couldn't execute query2!");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $username= $u;
        session_register('Login');
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        echo "1";
}
}


?>
```

Comment: You should escape your variable `$u` and `$p` before inserting them in your query.  The reason is someone could access any account via SQL injection.  Let's say I send the user `admin` and the password `' or '' = '`, your SQL query will become `SELECT * FROM Login WHERE login_user ='admin' AND login_pass='' or ''=''`.  Assuming you have a user named `admin`, I would get access to this account without even knowing the password.